# Multiple validations with Joi

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm new to using Joi validations and I need your help. I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Get error message for all empty fields in Postman which are required in Joi
2. Requesting a user to enter all or one of the valid values when they hit PATCH request.

I have tried this:

1. Returning an error message when one field is empty by when all fields are empty in postman (when I send no request) I still get an error for the first field yet I want a list of error messages for all empty fields.

**Joi User signup validation**

```
import Joi from "joi";

export const validateSignup = user => {
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .max(20)
      .required()
      .error(() => "first_name must be a string"),
    last_name: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .max(20)
      .required()
      .error(() => "last_name must be a string"),
    email: Joi.string()
      .email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
      .trim()
      .required()
      .error(() => "email must be a valid email"),
    password: Joi.string()
      .regex(
        /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/
      )
      .required()
      .error(
        () =>
          "password must be at least 8 characters long containing 1 capital letter, 1 small letter, 1 digit and 1 of these special characters(@, $, !, %, *, ?, &)"
      )
  });

  const options = { abortEarly: false };
  return Joi.validate(user, schema, options);
};
```

**Sign up controllers**

```
import { validateSignup } from "../helpers/userValidator";

class User {
  static async SignUp(req, res) {
    const { error } = validateSignup(req.body);
    if (error) {
      return res
        .status(400)
         .json(new ResponseHandler(400, (error.details || []).map(er => er.message), null).result());
    }
  }
}
```

**ResponseHandler Class**

```
class ResponseHandler{
    constructor(status, message, data, error){
        this.status = status; 
        this.message = message; 
        this.data = data, 
        this.error = error;
    } 

    result(){
        const finalRes = {};
        finalRes.status = this.status;
        finalRes.message = this.message; 
        if(this.data  !== null){
            finalRes.data = this.data;
        }else if(this.error !== null){
            finalRes.error = this.error;
        }
        return finalRes;
    }
}


export default ResponseHandler;
```

**Postman response**

[image: Postman's response body]

I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just using sending the `0`th element that's why you are getting only one error.

Instead of `error.details[0].message` use

```
(error.details || []).map(e=>e.message)
```

**Explanation:**
`Joi` has all the errors stored in `error.details` array. You just have to format it your way using the values you like.

For example for this object:

```
{
  first_name: null,
  last_name: null,
  email: null,
  password: null
}
```

Errors are:

```
[ { message: 'first_name must be a string',
    path: [ 'first_name' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: { value: null, key: 'first_name', label: 'first_name' } },
  { message: 'last_name must be a string',
    path: [ 'last_name' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: { value: null, key: 'last_name', label: 'last_name' } },
  { message: 'email must be a valid email',
    path: [ 'email' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: { value: null, key: 'email', label: 'email' } },
  { message:
     'password must be at least 8 characters long containing 1 capital letter, 1 small letter, 1 digit and 1 of these special characters(@, $, !, %, *, ?, &)',
    path: [ 'password' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: { value: null, key: 'password', label: 'password' } } ]
```

Comment: thanks for the input. However, I tried your solution but it's still giving me the first element's error message. It's not returning the whole array of error messages.

Comment: That is not possible. What did you write in the `SignUp` function? Also post the relevant parts of the `ResponseHandler` class.

Comment: looks alright, I think you forgot to restart the node server after the changes. Because at the very least, it would have been enclosed in `[..]`.

Comment: I tried to restart the server but it's not working. Thanks a lot though, this is very close to what I was looking for.  I will keep searching, I'm just rushing right now.

Comment: ```{ status: 400,
  message:
   [ 'first_name must be a string',
     'last_name must be a string',
     'email must be a valid email',
     'password must be at least 8 characters long containing 1 capital letter, 1 small letter, 1 digit and 1 of these special characters(@, $, !, %, *, ?, &)' ],
  error: undefined }```

Comment: this is what I am getting. So, the code is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201931/discussion-between-mo1-and-aritra-chakraborty).

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713032/how-to-validate-nested-object-whose-keys-should-match-with-outer-objects-another ?