# How to validate nested object whose keys should match with outer objects another key whose value is array using Joi?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I have object which I want to validate.

```
// valid object because all values of keys are present in details object
var object = {
    details: {
        key1: 'stringValue1',
        key2: 'stringValue2',
        key3: 'stringValue3'
    },
    keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
}

// invalid object as key5 is not present in details
var object = {
    details: {
        key4: 'stringValue4'
    },
    keys: ['key4', 'key5']
}

// invalid object as key5 is not present and key8 should not exist in details
var object = {
    details: {
        key4: 'stringValue4',
        key8: 'stringValue8',            
    },
    keys: ['key4', 'key5']
}
```

All the keys present in `keys` should be present in `details` also.

I tried this using [Joi.ref()](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7#refkey-options)

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    details: Joi.object().keys(Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries({...Joi.ref('keys')}).map(([a,b]) => ({ [b]: Joi.string() })))),
    keys: Joi.array()
})
```

But this is not working because `Joi.ref('keys')` will get resolved at validation time.

How can I validate this object using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`object.pattern`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) and [`array.length`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options)

```
var schema = Joi.object({
  details: Joi.object().pattern(Joi.in('keys'), Joi.string()),
  keys: Joi.array().length(Joi.ref('details', {
      adjust: (value) => Object.keys(value).length
    }))
});
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uhvdpd?file=index.js)

Comment: What if I want to check one of the schemas to validate against the array items and if it matches move to the next item? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the array(if you want) then make a dynamic schema and validate that.

```
const arrSchema = Joi.object({
    keys: Joi.array()
});
```

then,

```
const newSchema = Joi.object({
    details: Joi.object().keys(data.keys.reduce((p, k) => {
        p[k] = Joi.string().required();
        return p;
    },{})),
    keys: Joi.array()
})
```

This should probably do it.

You have to set `allowUnknown: true` in `validate()` option.

Comment: dont hardcode `key1`, `key2`, `key3` than can be anything. we have to access that using `joi.ref('keys')`

Comment: added a simple two step solution.

Comment: What if I want to check one of the schemas to validate against the array items and if it matches move to the next item? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple