# How to validate object with two max condition on a value in Joi?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I want to validate this object using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) with conditions:
`b` should be greater than 2.
`b` can not greater than `a`.
`b` can not greater than `600`

```
// valid object
var object = {
    a: 5,
    b: 3
}

// invalid object because b > a
var object = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6
}
```

I treid to build Joi schema

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().min(2).max(Joi.ref('a')).max(600)
})
```

This schema is ignoring `b<=a` condition so invalid object is also seen as valid. What should be correct schema to apply all the conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`less()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#numberlesslimit) which specifies that the value must be less than limit or a reference.

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().less(Joi.ref('a')).min(2).max(600)
})
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xvhrpk?file=index.js)

Comment: it should use `less()` instead of `greater()`

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor Its updated. Kindly accept the answer if it helps

Comment: can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713032/how-to-validate-nested-object-whose-keys-should-match-with-outer-objects-another

Answer (score 1):

```
var schema = Joi.object({
a: Joi.number().integer(),
b: Joi.number().integer().min(2).max(Joi.ref('a')).less(601)
})
```

Comment: var schema = Joi.object({
a: Joi.number().integer(),
b: Joi.number().integer().min(2).less(Joi.ref('a')).max(600)
})