# object.pattern() is not working correctly inside array.items() in Joi

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I am trying to validate nested object whose keys should match with outer objects another key whose value is array using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)
I tried to use [object.pattern](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) and [array.length](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) which is demonstrated at [How to validate nested object whose keys should match with outer objects another key whose value is array using Joi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713032/how-to-validate-nested-object-whose-keys-should-match-with-outer-objects-another)

But that is not working with array.items()

```
var object = {
    details:[{
        key1: 'someValue',
        key2: 'someValue',
        key3: 'someValue'
    },{
        key1: 'someValue',
        key2: 'someValue',
        key3: 'someValue'
    }],
    keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
}

var schema = Joi.object({
    keys: Joi.array().length(Joi.ref('details', {adjust: (value) => Object.keys(value).length})),
    details: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().pattern(Joi.in('keys'), Joi.string()))
})

console.log(schema.validate(object)) // this should not give error but I am getting error
```

I am getting error

```
{ value:
   { details: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     keys: [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' ] },
  error:
   { ValidationError: "details[0].key1" is not allowed
     _original: { details: [Array], keys: [Array] },
     details: [ [Object] ] } }
```

How to make this validation working without hardcoding keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Joi.ref('details', {adjust: (value) => Object.keys(value).length})`,

**Problem** - Here `value` refers the `details` which is an array. So `Object.keys(<details-array>).length` won't work as expected

**solution** - map `value` array with `Object.keys().length` and use the maximum as given below

---

`Joi.object().pattern(Joi.in('keys'), Joi.string())`,

**Problem** - `keys` refers the sibling of `details`

**solution** - add `/` as prefix which is root of object

---

```
var schema = Joi.object({
  details: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().pattern(Joi.in('/keys'), Joi.string())),
  keys: Joi.array().length(
    Joi.ref('details', {
      adjust: value => {
        return Math.max(...value.map(o => Object.keys(o).length));
      }
    })
  )
});
```

**[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-88pbag?file=index.js)**

**Reference**

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#Relative-references

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933028/how-to-check-key-order-in-json-object-using-joi